# Find key in string with python

Tags: python, string, contains

I have string `text` that I want to find if it contains 1 of some value from list , I build this code

```
text='abcdefg'
magic=['4','6','e']
any(x in str(text) for x in magic)
```

That works fine.

But How can I know what is the value that find? in this example I want to print `e`

Comment: If you need only the first one you find: `next((x for x in magic if x in text), None)` (with  `None` as the default value if we don't find anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the `magic`and build a new list with all found variables:

```
text='aabbccddeeffgg'
magic=['4','6','e']
a = [x for x in magic if x in text]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text='aabbccddeeffgg'
magic=['4','6','e']
list = []
for x in text:
    if x in magic:
        list.append(x)
print(list)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save some iterations you could also stop  when the first match is found

```
def find_first_occurrence(txt, keys):
    for key in keys:
        if key in txt:
            return key

text='aabbccddeeffgg'
magic=['4','6','e']
match = find_first_occurrence(text, magic)
if match:
    print(match)
```